# Cross compiling zbar c library for windows

Tags: c, gcc, rust, mingw-w64, zbar

I'm writing a program in rust that makes use of the [zbar library](https://github.com/mchehab/zbar), using rust bindings for zbar from [magiclen](https://github.com/magiclen/zbar-rust) and want to extend the build script to support building from source. libzbar is normally built with autotools but I had separate issues with that, so I'm trying to use [CC](https://github.com/alexcrichton/cc-rs) in a build script.

```
    cc::Build::new()
        .warnings(false)
        .extra_warnings(false)
        .define("HAVE_CONFIG_H", "1")
        .include("./zbar")
        .include("./zbar/zbar")
        .include("./zbar/include")
        .static_flag(true)
        .file("./zbar/zbar/config.c")
        //...all the other C files needed...
        .file("./zbar/zbar/decoder/sq_finder.c")
        .compile("zbar");
```

However when cross-compiling for windows, `ld` breaks because of undefined references to `iconv`, `iconv_close` and `iconv_open`:

```
cargo build --target=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
#...snip...
error: could not compile `zbar-rust`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: linking with `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" #snip.. long list of options
  = note: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/debug/deps/libzbar_rust-770a0ffd35ecffdf.rlib(qrdectxt.o): in function `qr_code_data_list_extract_text':
          /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:81: undefined reference to `iconv_open'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:83: undefined reference to `iconv_open'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:85: undefined reference to `iconv_open'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:87: undefined reference to `iconv_open'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:261: undefined reference to `iconv'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:301: undefined reference to `iconv'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:319: undefined reference to `iconv'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:403: undefined reference to `iconv_open'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:412: undefined reference to `iconv_close'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:420: undefined reference to `iconv_close'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:483: undefined reference to `iconv_close'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:484: undefined reference to `iconv_close'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:485: undefined reference to `iconv_close'
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/debug/deps/libzbar_rust-770a0ffd35ecffdf.rlib(qrdectxt.o):/home/mehow/Dropbox/code_backups/zbar-rust/./zbar/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c:486: more undefined references to `iconv_close' follow
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How do I include libiconv?

I've set the the x86_64-pc-windows-gnu target to use my system mingw in my cargo config:

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]
linker = "/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc"
ar = "/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ar"
```

My mingw install definitely has iconv, and it contains the symbols I need:

```
$ ls /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/ | grep iconv
libiconv.a
libiconv.dll.a
$ nm /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a | grep iconv
win_iconv.o:
0000000000001df0 T iconv
0000000000001da0 T iconv_close
0000000000001ae0 T iconv_open
00000000000016a0 t win_iconv
0000000000000000 t win_iconv_close
```

I've tried telling CC to include my mingw lib directory using `.include`:

```
    cc::Build::new()
        //...
        .include("/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib")
        //...
```

And also explicitly including it via `.flag`:

```
    cc::Build::new()
        //...
        .flag("-I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib")
        .flag("-liconv")
        //...
```

But I still get the same undefined iconv reference errors in both cases.

Note that the library builds fine when targeting my native target `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`